# Phaser: Tween in different functions sets object to undefined

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I've got some sprites that I tween in on a function call, like so:

```
moveSlotMachineIn() {
    var comboBaseTweenIn = this.game.add.tween(this.comboBase).to({x: 10}, 2000, "Quart.easeOut", 3000);
    var comboTopTweenIn = this.game.add.tween(this.comboTop).to({x: 10}, 2000, "Quart.easeOut", 3000);
    var comboMaskTweenIn = this.game.add.tween(this.comboMask).to({x: 10}, 2000, "Quart.easeOut", 3000);
    var arrowGrpTweenIn = this.game.add.tween(this.arrowSlotGroup).to({x: 200}, 2000, "Quart.easeOut", 3000);
  }
```

This works, and upon function call, the sprites do slide in from the left, to the right.

Now, I'm also supposed to slide the objects out. This is done via timer, so that it doesn't immediately slide out, like so:

```
this.game.time.events.add(3000, this.comboLayer.moveSlotMachineOut, this);
```

That calls this function:

```
moveSlotMachineOut() {
    console.log(this.comboBase);
    var comboBaseTweenOut = this.game.add.tween(this.comboBase).to({x: 1600}, 2000, "Quart.easeOut", 3000);
    var comboTopTweenOut = this.game.add.tween(this.comboTop).to({x: 1600}, 2000, "Quart.easeOut", 3000);
    var comboMaskTweenOut = this.game.add.tween(this.comboMask).to({x: 1600}, 2000, "Quart.easeOut", 3000);
    var arrowGrpTweenOut = this.game.add.tween(this.arrowSlotGroup).to({x: 1600}, 2000, "Quart.easeOut", 3000);
  }
```

But for some reason, I get the following error:

> phaser.js:64795 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of
>   undefined

Which is pointing to `this.comboBase` of `moveSlotMachineOut()`. What is also weird is that the `console.log` bit in said function returns **undefined**.

Here's my initialization of `this.comboBase`:

```
 this.comboBase = this.game.add.sprite(this.x -10, this.y, 'ui');
 this.comboBase.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
 this.comboBase.frameName = 'ui_specialBase.png';
```

The rest of them are somewhat similar. To my knowledge, I do not clear the values of the variables, so I'm not sure what's happening.

What could be causing the variables to be undefined? Does tweening do anything?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, open and close parenthesis can mean all the difference.

Changing this:

```
this.game.time.events.add(3000, this.comboLayer.moveSlotMachineOut, this);
```

To this:

```
this.game.time.events.add(3000, this.comboLayer.moveSlotMachineOut(), this);
```

Now that would create an entirely different error, as (AFAIK) `.add` doesn't like anything with parenthesis, so the final code is:

```
this.game.time.events.add(3000, function() {this.comboLayer.moveSlotMachineOut()}, this);
```